# UISearchBar placeholder crash in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uisearchbar, xcode6, placeholder

I have a UISearchBar programatically and works but if I try to set a placeholder and user tap to search something my app crash. This is my code:

**Property**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchBar *mySearchBar;
```

**Implementation**

```
self.mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
self.mySearchBar.delegate               = self;
self.mySearchBar.autoresizingMask       = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.mySearchBar.autocorrectionType     = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
self.mySearchBar.translucent            = NO;
self.mySearchBar.returnKeyType          = UIReturnKeySearch;
self.mySearchBar.autocorrectionType    = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
self.mySearchBar.inputAccessoryView     = toolBarKeyboard;
self.mySearchBar.placeholder            = @"Artist, Team or City";
```

**This line makes crash when user tap in uisearchbar to find some data**

```
 self.mySearchBar.placeholder            = @"Artist, Team or City";
```

**Someone else with this error?**

I use:

- Xcode 6
- iOS 8
- iPhone 5 / 5s

Comment: This is the error:  -[SearchViewController _searchController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a09f0f0

Comment: Is `SearchViewController` your class? Does your class try to access the `_searchController` property/ivar? Show that code.

Comment: Yes, SearchViewController is my class and i create a UISearchBar like string property and add it in navigation bar: self.navigationItem.titleView = self.mySearchBar;

Comment: That's not what I asked. Do you have any code that makes use of the `_searchController` value?

Comment: Hi, Pardon me. Yes i found the error.  I Have this code uncommented to take control on uisearchbar's uitextfield:

UIView *viewToGetClearButton = [self.mySearchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    for (UIView *view in viewToGetClearButton.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]])
        {
            UITextField *txt       = (UITextField *)view;
            txt.delegate           = self;
            break;
        }
    }

I Just delete this code and works!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but if someone else is facing this issue, this can solve the problem:

```
UITextField* tfSearchBar = [self.mySearchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
tfSearchBar.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Artist, Team or City"];
```

Hope it helps